# How to change parameter and value selected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to change parameter within the Observable method and receive value according to value obtained on click

```
 orderItem(item: string, value: string) {

   switch (value) {

    case 'status':

    this._sortService.listSort(this._sortService.filter, { sort: { 
     "colaborator.status": 1 } }).subscribe(res => {

      this.dataSource = res.data;
     
      }, err => {
      console.info('### ERRO sort', err);
       });

       break;

  
         default:

      }

     }
```

Exemple value:  Status and name

```
                        <ng-container>
                            <th headerCell column="status" 
                                (click)="OrderItem($event, 'status')">
                                Status</th>
                            <td *cell="let element" (click)="open()">
                                {{element.colaborator.status)}}
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container>
                            <th *headerCell column="name"
                                (click)="orderItem($event, 'name')">Name</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ element.name }}
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>
```

I wish I didn't have to duplicate the Subscribe method: this._sortService.listSort

Comment: Something similar to `const sortArg: any = value === 'status' ? {"colaborator.status": 1 } : {};` and then pass that `sortArg` as the value to `sort` in the 2nd parameter of `listSort`.

Comment: @Igor Thanks Igor, I will try it this way